# Образование слова становиться

Tags: словообразование

От какого слова образовалось слово становиться: от слова становить или от стать? Обычно несовершенный вид образуется от совершенного вида. Учительница утверждает, что оно образовалось от становить при помощи постфикся ся. Но ведь несовер.вид не образуется от несовершенноого.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Комментарии по тексту**

Глагола «становить» **в русском языке нет**, поэтому мы не можем образовать глагол "становиться" от несуществующего слова.

Исторически с глаголом "стать" связаны **приставочные** глаголы *остановить*, *установить*,  но в современном языке они будут считаться непроизводными, в них выделяется корень ОСТАНОВ- и УСТАНОВ-.

Что касается **частицы СЯ,** то она   используется при образовании новых слов для обозначения **возвратности**, но  видовые пары при этом не образуются, например: вертеть — вертеться, одеть — одеться (сов. или несов. вид глагола сохраняется).

Кстати, мы можем образовать **глагол несов. вида  от глагола несов. вида**, например: плясать — приплясывать.

2. **О глаголе  "становиться"**

Согласно словарю (на Грамоте.ру)  существует видовая пара: ***стать – становиться***, которая образуется **супплетивным** способом [фр. suppletif — добавочный].

Из словаря: 2. **СТАТЬ**, стану, станешь; **св**.  **7. (нсв. становиться).** Употр. как вспомогательный глагол в составном именном сказуемом со зн.: сделать кем-, чем-л., каким-л., прийти в какое-л. состояние. С. агрономом. С. учёным, бизнесменом, менеджером, фермером. Лицо стало печально. безл. Мне стало страшно.

Примеры **супплетивных пар**, восходящих к разным словам: ловить — поймать, говорить — сказать, брать — взять. Но пары бывают и однокоренные: лечь — ложиться, сесть — садиться, ***стать — становиться***, лопнуть — лопаться.

В этих случаях «формы несовершенного вида **более сложны** по составу в сравнении с формами совершенного вида, однако те различия, которые существуют между ними, **невозможно объяснить** фонетическими и морфологическими закономерностями, действующими **в современном русском языке**».

Таким образом, на уровне современного языка мы не  выделяем в паре ***стать – становиться***  словообразовательные элементы.

Соответственно, можно сделать вывод, что глагол "становиться" **является непроизводным.**

**Примечание**

1. Вам желательно ознакомиться **со способами образования видовых пар**,  и тогда вы увидите, что возможны  **оба варианта:**  (1) **перфективация** — образование глаголов совершенного вида от глаголов несовершенного вида (знать – узнать, толкать – толкнуть);  (2) **имперфективация** — образование глаголов несовершенного вида от глаголов совершенного вида (рассказать – рассказывать, решить – решать).

https://goldrussian.ru/obrazovanie-vidovyh-par-glagola.html

https://studopedia.net/7_29269_sposobi-obrazovaniya-vidovih-par.html

2. Но как же всё-таки образовался глагол ***становиться***? Желательно, конечно, поискать исторический материал в Сети с объяснением такого словообразования, но  можно (только **лично для себя**, не для учительницы) попробовать объяснить (**пофантазировать**)  самому.

Обычно несовершенный вид образуется с помощью суффикса ЫВА/ИВА, но видовой суффикс ОВА/ЕВА тоже иногда встречается, например: затмить –  затмевать, продлить – продлевать. Тогда бы у нас получилось так: стать – стану – становать/становить. Но суффикс  И чаще используется в переходных глаголах, поэтому, чтобы обозначить непереходность, добавляем частицу СЯ. Но это всего лишь "опыт" нашей исторической реконструкции, но никак не схема современного словообразования.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень интересно. О способах словообразования я знаю. Но вот этот глагол ввел меня в забоуждение.

Comment: И к какому итогу вы пришли?

Comment: Я думаю, что  видовая пара образуется супплетивным способом, но сам глагол "становиться" в современном языке будет считаться непроизводным. Как считает компьютерная программа, способ образования слова не удалось определить. Например: https://vnutrislova.net/разбор/по-составу/становится

Comment: Тут вот что интересно.  Глагол «стать» с корнем СТА  многозначный, рассмотрим, к примеру,  значения «разместить и разместиться».  Нам нужны  две видовые пары с разной переходностью, и мы их получаем:  ставить – поставить,  стать – (становить) – становиться.  Форма «становить» чисто техническая,  он дублирует значение  «ставить».  Для формального словообразования она является промежуточной, поэтому в языке не используется (но зато используются ее приставочные формы). Если рассмотреть пару ста/ть – ста/нови/ть/ся, то словообразовательный формант должен иметь такой вид: (Н) ОВИ (СЯ).

Comment: Разумеется, это очень частный случай, поэтому как регулярный способ он рассматриваться не будет. Соответственно,  удобнее считать «становиться» непроизводным глаголом.

Answer (score 4):

Из словаря-справочника (под ред. Л.И. Рахмановой) **"Трудности русского языка" (4-е изд., перераб. — М., 2011)**:

> **Ставить — становить**. Многозначному стилистически нейтральному глаголу *ставить* синонимичен во всех своих значениях просторечный
> глагол *становить*...

Именно от глагола *становить* и образует Тихонов в своём **"Словообразовательном словаре русского языка" (М., 1990)** слово *становиться*:

> **становить** —> становить-**ся**.

Такое же образование слова *становиться* предлагается и в **"Большом универсальном словаре русского языка" под ред. В.В. Морковкина (М., 2016)**.

Comment: «Поклали» — неграмотно, — сказал Акопян.

— «ПОКЛАЛИ шапки» — это экспрессия, масса, мускул, акт! — сказал Железный. — Вы полагаете — в слове все исчерпывается его грамотностью?

— В трамваях висит объявление, — сказал Акопян со своим мягким акцентом, — напечатанное, кстати, у нас в типографии: «Детей СТАНОВИТЬ на скамейку ногами воспрещается». Может быть, вам нравится слово «становить»?

— А конечно, потому что в нем образ! — воскликнул Железный. — СТАВЯТ клизму, как вы не понимаете, черт вас возьми! Слово «ставить» тут немыслимо даже ритмически.

Comment: «Детей ставить на скамейку ногами»… Слышите?! Фраза кособочится, у нее заплетается язык! Это объявление набирал ЛИНГВИСТ, УМНИЦА! И разве не восхитительно «становить ногами», как будто можно становить и головой, разве в этом не эпоха?

Comment: Так что умницы наши лингвисты, которые от просторечных глаголов образуют стилистически нейтральные. Это же просто восхитительно и, главное, ритмически верно. Кстати, а куда просторечный глагол пропал из толковых словарей? У Кузнецова его нет, у Ефремовой вроде бы тоже. Даже у Ушакова нет и у Ожегова нет. Везде пишут: опечатка. Ну и еще вопрос: просторечный глагол у нас непроизводный или верно: стать — ста/н/ови/ть? Тогда уж и частицу СЯ можно добавить (что уж мелочиться): стать - ста/н/ови/ть/ся. И никакого супплетивизма не будет.

Comment: У Ушакова есть ( http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=73955 ), но действительно, странно ожидать, что от него могло образоваться нечто более употребительное. Да и свидетелей последовательности образования словесных форм (да ещё во всех частных случаях) нет и быть не может - эта химера происходит из учебных схем словообразования с табличками :).

Comment: Да, у Ушакова в интернете я видел. И даже прислали мне скриншот из бумажного словаря, в котором это слово есть

Comment: Ну что ж, подведем  итоги. Толковый словарь Ушакова был издан в 1935—1940 годах, и уже там «становить» – ОБЛАСТНОЕ ПРОСТОРЕЧИЕ.  «Сентиментальный роман» В. Пановой, который я цитирую,  — это книга о советской молодежи 1920-х годов, созданная на автобиографическом материале. Уже тогда слово было серьезным нарушением грамотной речи.  И вот сто лет спустя считается возможным использовать его в качестве производного слова в СОВРЕМЕННОЙ грамматике. Что же нам ждать от такого образования, полученного  под ред. В.В. Морковкина (М., 2016).

Comment: И еще любопытный момент. В словаре Кузнецова дается два основных значения глагола стать – пространственное и временное. И вот во временном  значении глагол несовершенного вида «становиться» никак не может мотивироваться пространственным глаголом «становить». И как мы тогда его образуем? Что по этому поводу говорит Морковкин В.В.? http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=стать&all=x

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь, вы изрядно заплутали в формулировках.  Но попытаюсь привести к корректному виду.

В принципе-то тут вопрос выбора системы или методики. Можно по-разному трактовать. Но если оставаться в рамках школьных представлений, то предлагаю следующий поход.

> От какого слова образовалось слово становиться: от слова становить или от стать?

Исторически - от "становить". Напрямую от "стать" не получится потому, что тут сразу несколько словообразовательных элементов задействовано.

Ста..->стан->(у)становить->становиться
|
+--->Стать

Так что видовая пара стать-становиться не совсем обычная, в ней нельзя указать один глагол, который бы был напрямую образован от другого. Другими словами, здесь мы имеем дело с одним из вариантов супплетивизма, о котором так подробно пишет Sharon.

Видимо, именно это и имела в виду учительница, производя "становиться" не от "стать", а от глагола "?становить", существующего только в приставочном варианте.

> Но ведь несовер.вид не образуется от несовершенного.

Странное утверждение. Речь, видимо, идет о том, что в паре совершенный-несовершенный вид несовершенный считается образованным от совершенного, поскольку первый (несовершенный) обычно длинее второго (совершенного) на соответствующий суффикс: *дать-давать, убить-убивать, одолжить-одалживать*. Повторюсь: только в видовой паре и только при таком способе образования.

Все остальные случаи такому правилу не подчиняются. В частности, при словобразовании с помощью возвратного постфикса глагол вид не меняет: . Причем это так даже в самых хитрых случаях, когда, например, меняется само значение (*нести-нестись* - оба несов. в., *склонить-склониться* - сов. в.) и для двувидовых глаголов (*женить-женитьс*я).

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ (информация о словаре)**

Так как мои оппоненты не захотели обсудить со мной версию образования слова «становиться», то я решила поближе познакомиться с информацией **о словаре и его авторе.** Я думаю, всем будет интересно послушать, тем более что словарь часто фигурирует на форуме в качестве **доказательства самых современных лингвистических взглядов.**

**1. О словаре**

**«Большой универсальный словарь русского языка»** — результат 25-летнего труда **авторского коллектива Государственного института русского языка им. А. С. Пушкина**, осуществленный под руководством доктора филологических наук Валерия Морковкина.

Идея создания словаря была высказана Валерием Морковкиным **в 1973 году** в докладе «Об универсальном **учебном словаре** русского языка», но работа над нынешним словарем началась **с конца 1980-х годов**, и в его создании приняли участие Валерий Морковкин, Галина Богачева и Наталия Луцкая. Ректор Института Пушкина **Маргарита Русецкая** отметила, что институт издал в сотрудничестве с издательством «Словари XXI века» уже не один словарь.

**2. О В.В. Морковкине**

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Морковкин,_Валерий_Вениаминович](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

В.В. Морковкин ( 1940 — 2016) — советский и российский лингвист, **лексикограф, педагог**. Доктор филологических наук, профессор. Окончил филологический факультет Московского государственного университета имени М. В. Ломоносова (1967).
**В Научно-методическом центре** русского языка (впоследствии — Институте русского языка имени А. С. Пушкина) с 1967 года работал  **начальником отдела учебной лексикографии**. Внёс значительный вклад в русскую **лексикологию, общую и учебную лексикографию, теорию и практику обучения русскому языку нерусских.**

**3. Комментарий**

Морковкин, безусловно, интересный лингвист, но  круг его основных интересов составляли **специализированные словари:** идеографические (понятийные), тематические, структурные, также словарь сочетаемости слов.  Интересна тема **структурного словаря**, в котором представлено около 1200 основных структурных слов – вероятно, моделей,  характерных для русского языка.

**Словообразованием как таковым он, следовательно, не занимался,** и большинство его современных работ написано в соавторстве. Вот, к примеру, **последние издания:**  Система лексических минимумов современного русского языка (в соавторстве). **2002**. Большой универсальный словарь русского языка (в соавторстве). **2015**.

**4. Вывод**

Из этого следует, что Большой универсальный словарь русского языка –   это прежде всего **совместный труд авторского коллектива Государственного института русского языка им. А. С. Пушкина**, хотя он и называется: **Морковкин В.В. «Большой универсальный словарь русского языка».**

[https://books.academic.ru/book.nsf/63374239/Большой+универсальный+словарь+русского+языка](https://books.academic.ru/book.nsf/63374239/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C+%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Могу еще добавить, что лично я во всех областях науки предпочитаю **монографии, написанные узкими специалистами,** которые  наилучшим образом разбираются в заданной теме. А вот  **всё универсальное** вызывает у меня сомнения, поэтому я стараюсь такую литературу обходить стороной.
И сейчас что-то подсказывает мне, что  не стоит замирать в восхищении перед этим **универсальным учебным словарем**.

Также хотелось бы знать, кто из специалистов института при составлении словаря   **курировал тему словообразования** и какими источниками и монографиями он при этом пользовался? И вообще интересно, кто сейчас из филологов или научных коллективов **наиболее авторитетен** в этой области.

Надеюсь, что мои ответы помогут автору если и не сделать сразу окончательный выбор, то по крайней мере понять,что нет ничего истинного и абсолютного, что всё верно только в определенных пределах.  И главное  в нашей жизни – это научиться самостоятельно мыслить, а не просто доверять всему сказанному и написанному.