# Здесь же краткое прилагательное?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные, причастия, нн

Верны ли рассуждения?

**Дорога (какова?) заснеженна.**

или

**Дорога (что сделана?) заснежена.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***дорога заснежена.*** Это краткое причастие, одна буква Н.

Пояснение

1. Существует ли глагол **«заснежить»**? В орфографическом словаре он указан, да и в текстах встречается, хотя и не часто: ***Заснежило** все кусты и деревья, ходить по тайге стало невероятно трудно.* [Д. И. Саврасов. Таежные были и небылицы (2003-2008)]
2. От глагола образуется причастие, что также можно увидеть в словаре:

Большой толковый словарь

**ЗАСНЕЖЕННЫЙ,** -ая, -ое; -жен, -а, -о; (реже) ЗАСНЕЖЁННЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -жён, -жена, -жено. Покрытый, занесённый снегом. З. дом. З-ая стена. З-ые тротуары. З. путник. Двор весь заснежен. Кто-л. заснежен до неузнаваемости.

3. Но мы знаем, что причастие может **переходить в прилагательное**, например: *тучи **рассеяны** ветром – она задумчива и **рассеянна***;  В полной форме пишется две НН, а в краткой форме написание разное: НН в прилагательном и Н в причастии.
4. А как узнать, существует ли парное прилагательное. Самый важный признак – это не прямое, а **переносное значение** слова и наличие *прилагательных-синонимов*.

И вот у причастия «заснеженный»  нет переносного  значения и подходящих прилагательных-синонимов тоже нет. ***Заснеженный*** – это занесенный снегом (признак по действию). Следовательно, это причастие, а не прилагательное.

5. **Примеры**

Морозная тишина. В улицах ни души. Деревянные тротуары **заснежены**.

Впрочем, вот и зима: платформа **заснежена**, снег сухой, рассыпчатый и искристый.

Дорога сильно **заснежена**, трудная; пешая колонна все еще не подошла.

Answer (score 2):

> Верны ли рассуждения?
>
> **Дорога (какова?) заснеженна.**

Нет, не верны.

**Заснеженный** – прилагательное. Но не все отглагольные прилагательные в кратких формах имеют два **н**. В очень многих случаях для определения правильности их написания приходится обращаться к орфографическому словарю.

См. **Объяснительный русский орфографический словарь-справочник: [объяснение орфограмм, правила русского правописания, 20 000 словарных статей] / Е. В. Бешенкова, О. Е. Иванова, Л. К. Чельцова ; Ин-т русского яз. им. В. В. Виноградова РАН. - Москва : АСТ-Пресс, 2015**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

КОММЕНТАРИЙ  (по поводу словаря)

1. Я бы назвала этот словарь «запоминательным», а не объяснительным. Никаких объяснений я там не вижу, но предлагается запомнить большое количество кратких глагольных форм.

Можно предположить, что их **значительно больше** – ведь от многих переходных глаголов совершенного вида можно образовать причастие в краткой форме.

2. Орфографический справочник вводит **новую терминологию в грамматике?** Но определение частей речи дается в учебниках по морфологии, на них пользователи ориентируются при **грамматических разборах**, в том числе школьники.
3. А для чего вообще **всё это было нужно**? Могу предположить такую цель – выделить группу парных причастий и прилагательных вида «горы образованы – девушка образованна».  Здесь образуется причастие, которое может перейти в прилагательное, и тогда образуется пара слов с разным написанием в краткой форме.

Но таких пар очень немного – 20-30 самых употребительных, ну еще десяток можно добавить. Вот для них надо было бы составить **словарную статью**, а не все глаголы переписывать. Жаль, что у этой группы нет  закрепленного названия – например, отпричастные прилагательные.

4. Вероятно, составителям словаря было сложно понять довольно простую вещь (или они считают, что мы не можем этого понять).

Существуют отглагольные  прилагательные  вида «крашеный, мороженый, образованные  от глаголов **несовершенного вида** (они причастиями не могут быть по определению).  И есть причастия, которые переходят в прилагательные, если  приобретают переносное (только **качественное**) значение и уже не обозначают признак по действию.

5. Но об этом подробно написано **у Розенталя** – примеры он приводит,  но запомнить их не предлагает  (это не словарный материал). Об этом сказано во всех учебниках и справочниках  по морфологии.

Орфография – это вообще **прикладная наука**. Собственной теории в ней не так много, и она в основном базируется на смежных разделах (грамматике, фонетике).

Answer (score 1):

КОМММЕНТАРИЙ

на «КОММЕНТАРИЙ (по поводу словаря)» Sharon:

> …Но определение частей речи дается в учебниках по морфологии, на них
> пользователи ориентируются при грамматических разборах, в том числе
> школьники.

Немного из того, на что сейчас ориентируются школьники:

**Каверина, Валерия Витальевна.
*Русский язык. Углублённый курс подготовки к ЕГЭ : в помощь старшеклассникам и абитуриентам*** : [для старшего школьного возраста : 6+] / В. В. Каверина, Ф. И. Панков. - Москва : Эксмо, 2020. - 462, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRglY.jpg) с. : табл.; 22 см. - (Преподаватели филологического факультета МГУ имени М. В. Ломоносова) (Справочник для старшеклассников и абитуриентов).; ISBN 978-5-04-104066-6 : 4000 экз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Каверина, Валерия Витальевна  доктор филологических наук, 
https://www.philol.msu.ru/~ruslang/about/employee/kaverina.v.v/
Дисссертация 2010 года: Становление русской орфографии в XVII-XIX вв.: правописный узус и кодификация. Автор более 130 опубликованных работ, в том числе монографии «Узуальная норма деловой письменности XVII века: орфография префиксов» (М, 2004 «Орфография и пунктуация русского языка в таблицах» (М., 2016); «Русский язык: Орфография. Пунктуация» (М., 2017); «Русский язык: углублённый курс подготовки к ЕГЭ» в соавторстве с Ф. И. Панковым (М., 2020).

Comment: Специалист по орфографии  «считает», что имеет право менять терминологию в грамматике.  Мне бы хотелось ориентироваться на мнение профильных специалистов в этой области, в том числе в  авторитетных академических  изданиях, а не в книгах для абитуриентов, старающихся попасть в вуз.   Я еще раз повторяю, что грамматика – это основа языка,  в отличие от прикладного правописания.  А пособиями по ЕГЭ завалены все книжные прилавки (их не пишет только ленивый), притом что вопрос об его отмене пока еще стоит на повестке дня. На этом считаю дискуссию законченной, спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Sharon, как мне эти Ваши два комментария напомнили Ваше раннее: _Морковкин, безусловно, интересный лингвист, но круг его основных интересов составляли специализированные словари: идеографические (понятийные), тематические, структурные, также словарь сочетаемости слов…
Словообразованием как таковым он, следовательно, не занимался, и большинство его современных работ написано в соавторстве…_

https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461991/Образование-слова-становиться/462000#462000

Comment: Из сегодняшнего Вашего, Sharon, комментария: _Специалист по орфографии «считает», что имеет право менять терминологию в грамматике. Мне бы хотелось ориентироваться на мнение профильных специалистов в этой области…_ === Непонятно только, кого Вы считаете на сегодняшний день «профильными специалистами в этой области». По-моему, никого…

Comment: И что? К примеру, Свод 1956 года составляли семь академиков, вот их мнение, безусловно, заслуживает внимания. А здесь малоизвестная фигура меняет основные понятия в грамматике, и нужно ее слушать?

Comment: Я их вообще не считаю. Вот напишут новую академическую Грамматику, тогда и будет разговор. А вы посчитали, и что получилось?